# How do I make a simple dice game using python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a really simple dice game that :

- rolls two "dice" and stores their values in a list.

I need it to:

- return the values,
- point out where there are doubles,
- How many times doubles were rolled? and
- What roll they occurred on?

Here's what I have so far:

```
def dice():
    import random
    list1 = []

    for i in range (2):
        x = random.randint(1,6)
        list1.append(x)

    if list1[0] == list1[1]:
        print list1, "<-- DOUBLES"
        return
    else:
        return list1

counter = 0
for i in range (10):
    counter = counter + 1
    print "Roll", counter, "was", dice()

print "Doubles were rolled", ### times: on roll x, y, and z
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: please format your code better. There would be an error on line 2 since 'import random' is not tabulated (and also the rest of the code)

Comment: Also, what exactly is your question? Are you looking for code review, or do you have a specific problem you want to solve? Does something not work?

Comment: I'm sorry about the poor code formatting. I'm a little new to this. I'm trying to figure out how to count how many times doubles were rolled and how to which roll the doubles occurred on.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than have one continuous list of rolls, store the pairs of rolls as two-tuples in the list:

```
outcomes = []
for roll in range(rolls):
    outcomes.append(tuple(random.randint(1, 6) for _ in range(2)))
```

Or, as a more pythonic "list comprehension":

```
outcomes = [tuple(random.randint(1, 6) for _ in range(2))
            for _ in range(rolls)]
```

You can then iterate through to easily find pairs:

```
for index, roll in enumerate(outcomes, 1):
    if roll[0] == roll[1]:
        print("Roll {0} was a double {1}.".format(index, roll[0]))
```

Comment: Is it not more Pythonic to use a list comprehension for your first code snippet?

Comment: @AlexThornton yes it is, but I thought I would stick closer to the OP's starting implementation